# Issue inserting items into my sorted list?

Tags: c++, linked-list

So I've built a sorted linked list and it compiles and all that jazz, I insert the first item fine, but when I try to insert a second item, I get this error: `[main] 1000 (0) handle_exceptions: Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION` I did a bit of searching and found that it probably has to do with my insert function or my IsFull function (I'm only supposed to be able to insert 10 items into the list) - but for the life of me I can't figure out what's wrong with it.  Perhaps someone here could help? (I'm unsure if posting the entirety of the code will help, but I'm going to do so anyway)

NFL.h

```
#include <string>
const int MAX_ITEMS = 10;
enum RelationType  {LESS, GREATER, EQUAL};

using namespace std;
#ifndef NFL_H
#define NFL_H
struct NFL {
        string firstName;
        string lastName;
        string currentTeam;
        string position;
        string school;
};
#endif
```

sortedNFL.cpp

```
#include "sortedNFL.h"

struct NodeType
{
  NFL player;
  NodeType* next;
};

SortedNFL::SortedNFL()  // Class constructor
{
  length = 0;
  nflList = NULL;
}

bool SortedNFL::IsFull() const
{
  if (length == MAX_ITEMS || length > MAX_ITEMS)
  {
    return true;
  }
  else
    return false;
  /*NodeType* location;
  try
  {
    location = new NodeType;
    delete location;
    return false;
  }
  catch(std::bad_alloc exception)
  {
    return true;
  }*/
}

int SortedNFL::GetLength() const
{
  return length;
}

void SortedNFL::MakeEmpty()
{
  NodeType* tempPtr;

  while (nflList != NULL)
  {
    tempPtr = nflList;
    nflList = nflList->next;
    delete tempPtr;
  }
  length = 0;
}

NFL SortedNFL::GetItem(NFL& playerRequested, bool& found)
{
  bool moreToSearch; //flag for more items to search
  NodeType* location; 

  location = nflList; //initial location is first item in NFL list
  found = false; //flag for if item is found
  moreToSearch = (location != NULL);

  while (moreToSearch && !found) //while there is more to search and item is not found
  {
    if (playerRequested.lastName.compare(location->player.lastName) > 0)
    {
      location = location->next;
      moreToSearch = (location != NULL);
    }
    if (playerRequested.lastName.compare(location->player.lastName) == 0 && playerRequested.firstName.compare(location->player.firstName) == 0)
    {
      found = true; 
      playerRequested = location->player;
    }
    if (playerRequested.lastName.compare(location->player.lastName) < 0)
    {
      moreToSearch = false;
    }
  }
  return playerRequested;
}

void SortedNFL::PutItem(NFL inputPlayer)
{
  NodeType* newNode;    // pointer to node being inserted
  NodeType* predLoc;    // trailing pointer
  NodeType* location;   // traveling pointer
  bool moreToSearch;

  location = nflList;
  predLoc = NULL;
  moreToSearch = (location != NULL);

  // Find insertion point.
  while (moreToSearch) //while moreToSearch is true
  {
    if (inputPlayer.lastName.compare(location->player.lastName) > 0)
    {
      predLoc = location;
      location = location->next;
      moreToSearch = (location != NULL);
    }
    if (inputPlayer.lastName.compare(location->player.lastName) < 0)
    {
      moreToSearch = false;
    }    
  }

  // Prepare node for insertion
  newNode = new NodeType;
  newNode->player = inputPlayer;
  // Insert node into list.
  if (predLoc == NULL)         // Insert as first
  {
    newNode->next = nflList;
    nflList = newNode;
  }
  else
  {
    newNode->next = location;
    predLoc->next = newNode;
  }
  length++;
}
/*void SortedNFL::DeleteItem(NFL playerDeleted)
{
  NodeType* location = nflList;
  NodeType* tempLocation;

  // Locate node to be deleted.
  if (playerDeleted.lastName.ComparedTo(nflList->player) == EQUAL)
  {
    tempLocation = location;
    nflList = nflList->next;    // Delete first node.
  }
  else
  {
    while (playerDeleted.lastName.ComparedTo((location->next)->player) != EQUAL)
      location = location->next;

    // Delete node at location->next
    tempLocation = location->next;
    location->next = (location->next)->next;
  }
  delete tempLocation;
  length--;
}*/

void SortedNFL::ResetList()
{
  currentPos = NULL;
} 

NFL SortedNFL::GetNextItem()
{
  NFL playerRequested;
  if (currentPos == NULL)
    currentPos = nflList;
  playerRequested = currentPos->player; 
  currentPos = currentPos->next;
  return playerRequested;

} 
SortedNFL::~SortedNFL() //class destructor
{
  NodeType* tempPtr;

  while (nflList != NULL)
  {
    tempPtr = nflList;
    nflList = nflList->next;
    delete tempPtr;
  }
}
```

Comment: One potential problem is location can be null here `if (inputPlayer.lastName.compare(location->player.lastName) < 0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at the main loop you have in GetItem():

```
if (inputPlayer.lastName.compare(location->player.lastName) > 0)
{
  predLoc = location;
  location = location->next;
  moreToSearch = (location != NULL);
}
```

Let's pretend that `location` was pointing to the last element in your linked list, and the comparison evaluated to `true`. Inside the `if` statement you will therefore put `NULL` into `location`, this was the last element in the list.

So what happens immediately afterwards?

```
if (inputPlayer.lastName.compare(location->player.lastName) < 0)
```

Boom. Null pointer dereference. Undefined behavior.

Comment: Ah I see what the problem was, I needed an "else if" statement, not an if statement.  Thanks!

Comment: @TaiM. Even better would be to call `inputPlayer.lastName.compare(location->player.lastName)` and store the result in a variable. This way you only do the comparison *once* and test the single result twice. As written, if the first condition fails you will waste time calling the compare method again when the result is not going to be any different.  `int compare_result = inputPlayer.lastName.compare(location->player.lastName); if (compare_result > 0) { ... } else if (compare_result < 0) { ... }`  (And then if you did forget the `else` there would be no bug, just an extra integer comparison.)